# How to Inject multiple consumers in SimpleMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am writing a spring boot application, which consumes messages from RabbitMQ and processes it. Since the publisher is publishing messages at high speed, I want my consumer to process them at high speed as well.

My consumer code is NOT thread-safe.

Below is 1 possible way, I thought of implementing:

1. Mark the consumer scope as "prototype" and
2. Inject multiple consumers for the same class in "SimpleMessageListenerContainer "

How can I achieve this with below code?

```
@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames("MY_MESSAGE_QUEUE");
    container.setConcurrency("10");
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    <<How can I set multiple MessageListener here?????>>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the post at the link here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908387/2600196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each container can only have one listener instance.

If your listener is not thread safe you need a separate container bean for each instance, with `concurrentConsumers=1` (the default).

Comment: To get 10 consumers with a non-thread-safe prototype listener, you simply need 10 container `@Bean`s - `container1`, `container2`, ... `container10`. It's not clear why you need an example.